# How do i pass a list of strings as a SQL Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using entity framework. I have been told the suggested way of executing direct sql is to use
parameters instead of directly inserting values into the query string. i tried making invidual sql parameters and realize there is a 2100 parameter limitation (i had 8000 string params in the list)...
I can get this working by passing the value directly to the mySQLQuery string, but i want to know how
to passing it as a parameter to avoid sql injection attacks? I tried the code below

```
var mySQLQueryString = "...WHERE DataID IN (@mySQLVariable)";
List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@mySQLVariable", string.Join(",", dataList.ToArray()));
return context.Database.SqlQuery<ConcretePOCO>(mySQLQueryString, param).ToList();
```

When looking at it through a profiler, the data being sent to the SQL is '1,2,3,4'...i need it to be '1', '2', '3', '4'....

how do i accomplish this while sending as a parameter?

Comment: If you want to pass 2100 parameters you have a design issue. There's a reason you can't pass that many parameters *OR* use so many values in an `IN` clause.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not store the data in a temporary or staging table and join with the rest of your query? You can add an index on the join column and get *very* fast performance

Comment: For your string formatting, simply try adding the single quotes to: `string.Join("','", dataList.ToArray())`

Comment: @jcruz despite what the OP says, there's no reason at all for quoting. That parameter is a single value, no matter what it contains

Comment: @Daron, I think @PanagiotisKanavos is on to something. It's unclear what the big picture is here. But I suspect getting `'1', '2', '3', '4'` may not solve your problem. Have you tried hard coding that value and running the query in SSMS? If so, does it work? W/o really grasping the whole idea of what you are trying to do, it's hard to suggest a solution. But one question I have is: What is the upper range on how many items will be in `dataList`?  Will it be more than 2100?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - The problem with storing in a temp table is the reliance on the sql database...perhaps we decide to later decide to switch to DB2, or Oracle, or NoSQL, there is that dependency that we have to deal with...i want to minimize dependencies that each component is stand alone.

Comment: You can use dynamic sql and pass all your params along with their values as json string... Then use the json string to create your params and values.

Comment: @Daron you're using a database already, with vendor specific syntax. You're trying to use something that's definitely *not* valid syntax in *any* database.

Comment: @Casey Crookston - yes, i tried those hard coded values and they work. That is why i believe that the format is the only issue...i am trying to passing the values as parameters to avoid sql injection attacks. As of right now, i passing them directly in the sql string, and it works...but i want to pass it as a param.

Comment: Finally, you're doing something that just can't be made vendor-neutral: You're executing an ETL job. ORMs are meant to work with *entities* and map tables to entities. Not filter by 8000 rows. That's what databases are about.

Comment: @Daron no, the format isn't the issue. What you think you tried has nothing to do with parameters. That parameter is a single text value. That's it. End of story. And the syntax you use is SQL Server-specific

Comment: @Daron now, if you really want to send 8K rows, you can use a table-valued parameter *in SQL Server*. Other databases use different types, eg array types. None of these techniques is portable and all of them have different performance issues. In SQL Server for example, the TVP is assumed to have just 1 row as there are no statistics

Comment: @Daron, can you tell me how many items you expect to have in `dataList`?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - the query is not the issue...(it is long and complex and i didn't want to use the real table names here...that is why i simplified it to on where is necessary to understand the issue)...the query works if i directly insert the values....the query work if i used an sql parameter with one parameter. I don't worked when i try to send a list of parameters...but i think you are on to something with "use a table-valued parameter"...i am actually trying to get that working now....

Comment: @Casey Crookston - about 9000 in the dataList.

Comment: codexer - i will look into it now.

Comment: @@Panagiotis Kanavos - "the format isn't the issue. What you think you tried has nothing to do with parameters. That parameter is a single text value. That's it. End of story. And the syntax you use is SQL Server-specific" - i agree with you 100%. The issue is i want to pass 8000 parameters without hitting the 2100 parameter limitation.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - "if you really want to send 8K rows, you can use a table-valued parameter in SQL Server. Other databases use different types, eg array types. None of these techniques is portable and all of them have different performance issues. In SQL Server for example, the TVP is assumed to have just 1 row as there are no statistics" - Is it possible to use this table parameter in C#/Entity Framework? i am looking into this right now...it sounds like it is exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: @Daron Why dont you create an Entity Object, assign the values to its properties and the n insert it directly using context.EntityName.Add(Entity Object) for insertion.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Table Valued Parameters in EF :

Create a new `Type` in SQL

```sql
CREATE TYPE DataIds AS TABLE  
(  
    DataID int 
)
```

In your method, create a new `DataTable` from your list

```cs
using System.Ling;
using System.Data;
// ...

var dataIds = new DataTable();  
dataIds.Columns.Add("DataID", typeof(int));

List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
// do what ever to fill your list with parameters

foreach (String item in dataList)
{
    DataRow row = dataIds.NewRow();
    row["DataID"] = item;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

// When fetching data
var mySQLQueryString = "...WHERE DataID IN (SELECT DataID FROM @mySQLVariable)";
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@mySQLVariable", SqlDbType.Structured);  
param.Value = dataIds;  
param.TypeName = "dbo.DataIds";  
return context.Database.SqlQuery<ConcretePOCO>(mySQLQueryString, param).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a delimiter when passing to sql and then use STRING_SPLIT in the sql to break it up into a table.

Example:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@mySQLVariable", string.Join("**~**", dataList.ToArray()));
```

And then in sql do

```
select value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@mySQLVariable, '~')
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` exists only on SQL Server versions that also support JSON. It would be a lot safer to serialize the input data as JSON and parse it on the server. A better option would be to use a TVP, but all of these will be slow

Comment: This solution does work Casey (i tested it), but i am trying to avoid creating functions and  stored procs on the database. I don't want to deal with the dependencies.

Comment: (@Daron... not my answer. I only edited this answer to make it more readable. I am composing my own answer now.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways I can think of to get this done. One *possible* way of doing this is just to keep the work on the server, and not in the query. Keep in mind that depending on how much data we're talking about, this might not be the fastest process. But if we're only talking about 9,000, then it should be okay.

Using LINQ with Entity Framework, and if your Id's are alphanumeric, then this should work. Your syntax may vary based on your implementation...

```
var myResults= context.MyTable.Any(t => t.DataID.Intersect(dataList));
```

Now, if this ends up being too slow, then you can convert your list of ID's to a `HashSet`.

```
 var myHashSet = new HashSet<string>(dataList);   
 var myResults = context.MyTable.Where(t => myHashSet.Overlaps(t.DataID));
```

*(Disclaimer: I've not tested any of this. I'm going off memory.)*

Comment: The problem with this solution is the Ids are alphanumeric...(they can't be ints)

Comment: Ok! That beg's the question.. WHY are your ID's alphanumeric? But regardless, just change all instances of `int` to `string` and you should be good to go.